# Django 1.7 custom user model not migrated properly

Tags: django

I have created a custom user application.
My custom user  extends AbstractBaseUser...

In my settings file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_auth.CustomUser'
```

My custom user:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    DEGREE_CHOICES = zip( range(1,34), range(1,34) )
    class Meta:
         verbose_name = "user"

    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    )
    poster = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/poster/', blank=True, null=True) 
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100 )
    chapter = models.CharField(max_length=100 )
    lodge = models.CharField(max_length=100 )
    degree = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=DEGREE_CHOICES )
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    #REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name' ]
```

Now I am changing a lot of fields on custom_auth's models.py and trying to migrate it.
The fields that i have changed not changes at the database but newly added fields are added at the database.

How can i migrate a custom user properly? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: did you create and apply the migrations yet? `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: yes i have run that commands.

Comment: check if you have migrations folder in your app's directory and have *.py files in it